# How to convert windows identity to network credential in C#?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I want to pass credential of my application pool identity account to WCF service with in application ,I can get credential of application pool identity using

```
var identitipoolAccountCred = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

and I want to convert these credential (`System.Security.principal.WindowsIdentity`) to type  network credential type of (`System.Net.NetworkCredential`) to pass WCF channel factory.

So How to convert windows identity to network credential in C#?

Comment: This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319675/how-do-you-get-credentials-networkcredential-of-currently-logged-in-user